# Using activation code on Android App

Tags: android, activation

I am working on an app that would require an activation code in order to be used after being downloaded (user will get the code by postal mail). I understand that Apple will be rejecting the App, but can someone confirm if that functionality (activation code for an app) would be valid for Android? And that it could be used.

Before building up a prototype I would need to confirm this fact.

Anyhow, I will limit the audience of my App to Android users as I see that I have no options with MAC.

Comment: why an activation code? Isn't it enough to have purchased the app in the first place?

Comment: wait, will you send the code by **postal mail**? really??

@MarcB it seems he doesnt wanna share profits xD

Comment: @oPi What if it was a banking app and the user credentials were sent by mail due to security reasons? Did you think of that maybe?

Comment: ok, i think it will be valid. Anyway, if its not, an Android app can be downloaded from your projects webpage (because you have one, i hope). What i dont know if an user will pay for an activation code and wait a **postal mail** with it. Please, note that a postal mail just inside Spain will take at least 1 day

Comment: @Maggie a banking app has their own validating methods like code cards and similar. They dont send you a postal mail with an activation code. And also he would be worried about an iPhone/iPad app

Comment: @Marc: The activation code would be needed as depending on the code entered the content of the app will de different. No extra features, just the information will be different. Teh application itself will be free for the user.

Comment: @o_Pi: It is not the fact that I do not want to share profits :D, the model will be similar to the free apps that show ads. I will get the momeny from the ads that will be shown on the App, that - in this case - will be tailored to the user depending on the code that he entered on the activation.

Comment: @Maggie: Althought this is not the case, I agree that for security reasons sending the code by postal mail it is a good option. As you mention banks already do.

Comment: @oPi oh yes, they do. you register and get a part of the activation code through mail. not all of them do it that way and it's not the only way of doing it, but they do.

Comment: @Maggie you dont have to **activate the app**. You have to wait for your login credentials. The app isnt blocked.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [Google Play Developer Policies](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html) as your starting point (in particular the section "Paid and Free Apps").

If you are using activation codes to bypass app payments or in-app payments, you will be in violation of Google's policies. If the activation code is an integral part of your app's functionality (for example you are sending it by post to verify a user's address) then you *should* generally be okay.

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the idea is not to by pass Google to avoid the comission payment. The application itself will be free, but the ads that will be shown will depend on the activation code that has been used. This way the Advertisements can be better tailored to the application users. Do you believe that this will work out for Android?

Comment: Based on your description, this should be fine. I am not sure why you think this won't work on the Apple app store..

Answer (score 0):

I was using an app once that was later pulled from the Play store because you could purchase some premium features over PayPal (without Google Play). If you intend on charging for this code it might and probably will be an issue, however, if you will distribute the code free of charge to select customers it *might* work.

But, a better way of doing it would be with a Google Play group. You'd mark your app as beta and make a test group, that would only include the people you want.

But if you want to limit your audience there is really no reason to put your app on Google Play, just distribute your .apk file through your website, and have a serial code as a backup.

Comment: Thansk for your answer, and indeed the code distributed will be free of charge for the application users.  The idea of using a Google Play Group might not be the option, as the app will be distributed to every possible user.